# How do I hide an element after a delay from having it faded out using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation, toggle, hide, delay

```
$("div#whitebox p").click(function () {
    $("div#blackout").fadeTo(550, 0).delay(555).hide();
});
```

What I'm trying to accomplish with the above code is to have a certain div named blackout fade out and then get toggled off when I click on a paragraph tag in another div called whitebox. The reason why I need to toggle it off using the hide command is because if I don't do so, the blackout div, though faded out, still covers other links and makes them unclickable. However, with the code I am using, what happens is the fade animation doesn't work and the blackout div just gets toggled off instantly without even any delay. How do I improve this code so that the fadeout animation works as well as the hide() toggle command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fading it out completely since your opacity is 0.

Perhaps consider : [.fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) which will simulate the functionality you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Fadeout has a callback function itself:

```
$("div#whitebox p").click(function () {
    $("div#blackout").fadeOut(550, function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use fadeOut function. This function will set the the div display:none (Hence you need not call an explicit hide function.)

Usage:

```
$("div#whitebox p").click(function () {
    $("div#blackout").fadeOut(550);
});
```